# Saving a piped value went wrong

Tags: bash, pipe, command-substitution, json

I installed jq to handle some JSON with bash.
But somehow piping the JSON string to jq in combination with saving it's output to another variable went wrong.

```
TEST='{"foo": "bar"}'
PB_SIG=$TEST | jq '.foo'
echo $PB_SIG
```

It outputs just the whole TEST JSON string. Somebody?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this on the second line:

```
PB_SIG=`echo $TEST | jq '.foo'`
```

The two problems I see is that you need to echo the $TEST variable's value through the pipe and that you need to capture the output of the piped command.

Comment: Yes! I forgot the echo....... thank you. Did not know that.

Comment: Don't forget to quote the variable: `echo "$TEST"`

Comment: Why? It seems to work now.

Comment: Note that depending on the shell, `echo` may translate things like `\n` or `\t` to literal newlines and tabs, which would break when it arrives at `jq`.  It's better to use `printf`.

Answer (score 3):

Use this with bash:

```
TEST='{"foo": "bar"}'
PB_SIG=$(jq '.foo' <<< "$TEST")
echo "$PB_SIG"
```

Output:

```
"bar"
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a few issues in your code.  The immediate issue causing you your present problem is that you are using the wrong syntax.  To save the output of a command or a pipeline of commands in a variable, you likely want to use a command substitution, `variable=$(some command)`.

A second issue is your use of `$TEST` unquoted.  When the variable expansion is unquoted, the shell will split its value on spaces, tabs, and newlines (the contents of the `IFS` variable), and then apply filename globbing to each of the split-up bits.  This means that a JSON document like `{"foo": "a * bar"}` may end up outputted together with all the visible filenames in the current directory.

Yet another issue is your use of `echo` to output variable data.  If the JSON document contained a string with an encoded tab (`\t`) or newline (`\n`), then the `echo` may cause these to be expanded to literal tabs and newlines.  The following question with answers talks more in-depth about this: [Why is printf better than echo?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803)

Since you want to pass your JSON document from a shell variable to a `jq` expression to extract the value of the top-level `foo` key, we may do this like so:

```bash
document='{"foo": "bar"}'
signature=$( jq -n -r --argjson data "$document" '$data.foo' )
```

This creates a `jq` variable called `data` containing the JSON structure found in the `document` shell variable.  The `jq` command then extracts the `foo` key's value from this without reading any data from any file or data stream (since `-n` is used).  The extracted string is decoded (since `-r` is used) and stored in the shell variable `signature`.

To output the value of the `signature` variable:

```bash
printf '%s\n' "$signature"
```

... but if all you wanted to do was to output the value, then there is no point in first storing it in a shell variable.  Instead, you would let `jq` output the value directly by omitting the command substitution:

```bash
document='{"foo": "bar"}'
jq -n -r --argjson data "$document" '$data.foo'
```